# How to determine all sequences of genes, within an RNA , where a combination of G and T is repeated at least one single time

Tags: regex, shell

supose we have  this file RNA.txt

```sh
GGGT
CCAAA
AAAACCGGTT
CCCCT
AAAAAG
```

And I would like to search for all sequences composed of lettres  G and T repeated at least 1 time. such as AGTTG or   GGGGGT or maybe TAACGG  but not  AAAAT neither CCCCT ..etc.

I tried the command :

```sh
 grep -e "G\T+" RNA.txt
```

and I got the follwing output:

```sh
GGGT
AAAACCGGTT
AAAAAG
```

The first 2 sequences retrieved were correct but the AAAAAG  is wrong as it shoudl have at least one sequence of G and T in iany order to be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have:

```sh
cat file

GGGT
CCAAA
AAAACCGGTT
CCCCT
AAAAAG
AGTTG
GGGGGT
TAACGG
AAAAT
```

Then you can use this `grep` with an alternation regex:

```sh
grep -E 'G.*T|T.*G' file

GGGT
AAAACCGGTT
AGTTG
GGGGGT
TAACGG
```

- `-E`: enabled extended regex mode in `grep`. We may also use **`grep 'G.*T\|T.*G' file`**
- `G.*T|T.*G` will match a line with `G` and `T` in any order.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to grep all lines that have at least two G or two T:

```
grep -e "GG\|TT" RNA.txt
```

Fairly simple using the alternation operator `|`. The only gotcha: The operator needs to be escaped when grepping like that.